# How to make Mongoose unique key validation to pass if other key is different?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say we have this model :

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    uniqueCaseInsensitive: true,
    required: true,
  },
  organisation: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "organisation",
  }
});

const UserModel: mongoose.model("user", userSchema),
```

and we already have this document in our collection :

```
{
_id: "62e10be79f7ef6f083ca7827",
username : "John",
organisation : {
    "$oid": "62d08a16bf95e75ccbf23dcc"
  }
}
```

and we try to store a document with the same `username` we will get ***E11000 duplicate key error collection***

What if i want this unique validation to be triggered only when `organisation` is the same as well ?

So it will **NOT ALLOW** this to be stored :

```
    const user = new UserModel({
      name: "John",
      organisation: "62d08a16bf95e75ccbf23dcc",
    });
    await user.save();
```

But it will **ALLOW** this :

```
    const user = new UserModel({
      name: "John",
      organisation: "32d08y78bf95i75ccbf56dca",
    });
    await user.save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define compound index on schema level:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  organisation: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "organisation",
  }
});

userSchema.index(
    { name: 1, organisation: 1 }, 
    {unique: true, collation:{locale:"en", strength:2 }}
);
```

[collation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/reference/collation/) option relaxes  strength to 2 to make it case-insensitive

Comment: Thanks,is there a way to create a custom error message ? passing it like this  unique: [true, "Custom msg"], not working

Comment: No, not on Schema level. You can try-catch write operations, like `.save()` of course, but I guess it's not what you are asking.  For custom error messages you can use the mongoose-unique-validator plugin, just be aware it makes an extra .find() request before an update, and is prone to race conditions

Comment: mongoose-unique-validator somehow not picking up case insensitivity unique cases,using the compound indexing, (it does only when setting uniqueCaseInsensitive directly in schema) ,and in that case i get an error 11000,so i ended up catching the error in controller during .save() and setting custom error messages over there,is there any other solution,because honestly that way feels too hacky

Comment: Try to add `uniqueCaseInsensitive : true`  to the index definition. I wonder if it would help with mongoose-unique-validator.  As I said it still leave some room for race conditions, so it does not guarantee the custom error message 100%. try-catch does.

Answer (score 0):

use **mongoose-unique-validator** package.

```
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    uniqueCaseInsensitive: true,
    required: true,
  },
  organisation: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "organisation",
  }
});

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator,{ message: 'Error, expected {VALUE} to be unique.' });
const UserModel: mongoose.model("user", userSchema),
```

Comment: Could you explain ? Im already using this,for returning mongoose validation errors when unique is violated,can i use it also for what i'm asking ?

Comment: Yes you just need to add 
`organisation: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "organisation",
    unique: true,
    uniqueCaseInsensitive: true,
  }`

in schema.

Comment: Not working sorry,i'm afraid you did'nt understand my question..